# Suppress vibrate when docked?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, charging, vibrate

When I dock my iPhone in the charger (desk stand), it briefly chimes to say it's charging. If it's on silent, then it vibrates instead of chiming. When I go to bed and put the phone in the bedside charger, the noise from either is very annoying.

I want to suppress the vibrate-on-charge. How can I do that?

It's already jailbroken so suggestions in that genre are fine too.

Comment: I've added the jailbreak tag since there's no native way to do it.

Comment: I'd try using activator and SBSettings.

Comment: Both are installed. Are there any specific settings you can recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that PowerSoundDisabler  is most up to date and solves all this: http://www.ijailbreak.com/cydia/powersounddisabler-cydia-tweak/

Answer (score 5):

The only way I've found to deal with this on a non-jailbroken phone is to set the side switch to the non-silent setting, plug in headphones and then dock the phone. The chime sound will only play through the headphones and the phone will not vibrate.

Answer (score 3):

### For the vibration:

Since you jailbroken your iPhone already, use Silent Charge.

First, open Cydia and go to `Manage>Sources>Edit>Add`. Add the ModYouri repo (`http://repo.modyouri.com`) and select `Add Source`:

[image: add repo]

After adding, browse through the repo and find the `Silent Charge` package and install it.

[image: silent charge package]

After installing the package, Cydia will ask you to reboot. Reboot, and viola~! No charge vibration! If you want the vibration back, uninstall the package.

---

### For the sound:

Install WinterBoard and Silent Charge Classic (you can get it from the ModMyi repo). After installing both, launch WinterBoard and select Silent Charge Classic, and respring. Your iPhone should not make any sound after installation.

Comment: Fantastic! It doesn't disable the sound (if on) but it does disable the vibration when in silent mode. Since I had to add a new repo, another question arises: How could I have found this without asking here?

Comment: @torbengb: i updated my answer with instructions for disabling the sound

Comment: Thank you for the update. I already had WinterBoard installed but it doesn't list "Silent Charge". Did you really mean the "modmyi" repo, so there are two *different* "Silent Charge" apps? Or is there only one with that name? Going to Cydia>Manage>Sources>Modmyi I didn't see any app with that name.

Comment: @torbengb: whoops, should be silent charge classic. changing it.

Comment: Found it - and yes, it's on modMYi as you said, and though I didn't find it in the sources listing it did appear when I searched for it. Nice!